# When is the set statement: (A\B)⊕(A ∩ B) = A true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

"When is the set statement:

> (A\B)⊕(A ∩ B) = A

true? Is it sometimes true, never true, or always true? If sometimes, state the specific cases where it is. A & B are arbitrarily selected sets."

I said it was sometimes, as, it seems if A is empty and B is empty, then A\B is empty, A ∩ B is empty, and so the entire left side is then empty, and so is A. Would that be correct? Further, are there are other cases where this is a true statement?

Thank you for your time. ^^

Comment: What operation do you denote by $\oplus$ ? Is it symmetric set difference?

Comment: Are you the same person [who asked this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193396/when-is-the-set-statement-ab-a-b-true)? If so, why the second account?

Comment: ⊕ is denoting symmetric difference. Also, yes. New account just because I'm using my Yahoomail account this time, since I couldn't remember which password I used, I just logged in with this one.

Comment: @JessicaHope Then please stick to either one of the two.

Comment: Alrighty. I'll do so.

Answer (score 4):

If $A=\varnothing$, it doesn’t matter what $B$ is: $A\setminus B=\varnothing\setminus B=\varnothing$, and $A\cap B=\varnothing\cap B=\varnothing$, so $(A\setminus B)\oplus(A\cap B)=\varnothing\oplus\varnothing=\varnothing=A$.

But in fact it’s always true, for any sets $A$ and $B$. If $x\in A\cap B$, then $x\in B$, so $x\notin A\setminus B$. Conversely, if $x\in A\setminus B$, then $x\notin B$, so $x\notin A\cap B$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
(A\setminus B)\oplus(A\cap B)&=\Big((A\setminus B)\setminus(A\cap B)\Big)\cup\Big((A\cap B)\setminus(A\setminus B)\Big)\\
&=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\\
&=A\;.
\end{align*}$$

If you’re in doubt about that last step, notice that $A\setminus B$ consists of the things that are in $A$ but **not** in $B$, while $A\cap B$ consists of those things that are in **both** $A$ and $B$, so between them they pick up every element of $A$.

More generally, the symmetric difference of two disjoint sets is always their union:
if $X\cap Y=\varnothing$, then $X\oplus Y=X\cup Y$. Here the disjoint sets are $A\setminus B$ and $A\cap B$, and their union is $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes perfect sense, now. ^^

Answer (score 0):

We can easily demonstrate this by starting with the most complex (left hand) side, expanding the definitions (see [related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/576299/11994)), and simplifying: for every $\;x\;$,
\begin{align}
& x \in (A \setminus B) \oplus (A \cap B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\oplus\;$"} \\
& x \in A \setminus B \;\not\equiv\; x \in A \cap B \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definitions of $\;\setminus, \cap\;$"} \\
& x \in A \land x \not\in B \;\not\equiv\; x \in A \land x \in B \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"move $\;\lnot\;$ to the outside -- to prepare for the next step"} \\
& \lnot(x \in A \land x \not\in B \;\equiv\; x \in A \land x \in B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"factor $\;x \in A\;$ out of $\;\equiv\;$"} \\
& \lnot(x \in A \;\Rightarrow\; (x \not\in B \;\equiv\; x \in B)) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: contradiction"} \\
& \lnot(x \in A \;\Rightarrow\; \text{false}) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& x \in A \\
\end{align}
By set extensionality, this proves the statement in question.

Answer (score 0):

let $A,B \subset X$ and denote $(\forall Y), \bar Y=X \setminus Y$, then
$$(A\setminus B)\oplus(A\cap B) = (A \cap \bar B)\oplus(A\cap B)
= A \cap(\bar B \oplus B) = A \cap X = A
$$

Comment: took a while to get that right! dodgy trying to do math whilst on the phone. but it is a fairly simple derivation that is worth considering